# Good dynamics build issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, blackberry, good-dynamics

I get an error for GD framework saying
unable to spawn process '~/Library/Application Support/BlackBerry/Good.platform/iOS/FIPS_module/x86_64.sdk/bin/gd_fipsld' (No such file or directory)

Can you guess what could be wrong. Is the sdk not installed correctly or do i need to change any project settings in xcode.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In your xcconfig file can you update the path for ld to $(HOME)/Library/Application Support/BlackBerry/Good.platform/iOS/FIPS_module/$FIPS_PACKAGE/bin/gd_fipsld

notice the change from ~ to $(HOME), you might have to do that for ldplusplus

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by changing the xcode file system to Legacy build system from the default New build system. This is because the BB sdk cannot build yet with the New build system.

Comment: tried this as well but same issue I am getting. Even after I change LD and LDplusplus paths to $(Home) and file system to Legacy build. Any idea what could be the issue is?